# Elasticsearch error while parsing date from logs

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i have created ingest pipeline to fetch custom logs, my pipeline with processor looks like below

```
[
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "\\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\\] %{DATA:env}\\.%{DATA:log.level}: (?<message>(.|\r|\n)*)"
      ],
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "date": {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "formats": [
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSXX"
      ],
      "target_field": "@timestamp"
    }
  },
  {
    "json": {
      "field": "message",
      "add_to_root": true,
      "ignore_failure": true
    }
  }
]
```

now when i am sending logs with date format

```
 [2022-01-27T08:31:16.806171+00:00] local.INFO: {"request-id":"5f9c3819-97b3-4439-87ab-30c58bffd2a5","event_name":"cancel_pending_withdraw","message":"action webhook sent"}
 [2022-01-27T12:31:09.972653+00:00] local.INFO: {"request-id":"6cea1e1d-8e54-4225-b7d8-5383e39690bb","event_name":"deposit_approved","message":"Triggering all action now"}
```

it gives error

```
{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to parse date field [2022-01-27T10:22:49.234717+00:00] with format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSXX]","caused_by":{"type":"date_time_parse_exception","reason":"Text '2022-01-27T10:22:49.234717+00:00' could not be parsed at index 22"}}
```

can anyone help what exactly wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strict_date_optional_time_nanos` date format instead and it will work:

```
  {
    "date": {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"
      ],
      "target_field": "@timestamp"
    }
  },
```

Comment: I did this way but it only fetch first line from log file ignoring all others , check i have edited input file log in my question, i am only getting first line of log, i am expecting all line should be fetched, btw thank you your solution did worked not 100% as i expected but yes it worked

Comment: You need to send one line after another, as the ingest pipeline will process only one line at a time. You cannot send all lines in a single message field. how are you sending your logs to ES?

Comment: i have created one log file in my server where i have elastic agent installed which send my logs from that log file to my elastic search, so the log file keep on updating as we receive request on that server with unique request id, so as soon as we received request we want it to be log into elastic search which is working but it is logging only one line from that file not others.

Comment: ok, so Elastic Agent tails that file and only the first log line is being sent? weird... Do you see anything unusual in the agent logs or the ES server logs?

Comment: before it was waying date parse error, but after i implemented your solution it worked but only with one line, due thing i need to update JSON processor as well after updating date processor

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, the pipeline should work just fine, at least you don'g get the `illegal_argument_exception` error anymore, right? If yes, this question is answered and you can create another one which deals with the new issue